# Comodo SSL cert bundle installation Node.js / Express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl-certificate

I have just purchased a single domain SSL certificate from Comodo and have received the following files:

`example.com.ca-bundle`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGCDCCA/CgAwIBAgIQKy5u6tl1NmwUim7bo3yMBzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCB
hTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
lBlGGSW4gNfL1IYoakRwJiNiqZ+Gb7+6kHDSVneFeO/qJakXzlByjAA6quPbYzSf
+AZdAeKCIN2+b72z...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----  
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
MIIFdDCCBFygAwIBAgIQJ2buVutJ846r13Ci/ITeIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADBv
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJTRTEUMBIGA1UEChMLQWRkVHJ1c3QgQUIxJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFk
PUsE2JSDAD3FQdso8VYFhH2+9uRv0V9dlfmrPb2LjkQLPNlzmuhbsdjrzcd3h5vR
pu/xOD8QOG3...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

`example.com.crt`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGVDCCBTygAwIBAgIQDDhlxcL1PyJpGAoMWLNvwTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
wCypSjy5b3WKSdYByYwPZqKWKiqT/g3uLwD4fhWvqTQxmR9diXL1SAdZIwht47VU
7FytWidOUmY/lxVrlFDCePkWLkyAY0AN0VsocqB/16xq9LqN8FwWQg==... 

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

`index.js`

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
```

`example.com.ca-bundle` contains two certificates. What are they and which one do I use for `server.key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not provide the entire certificates we can't tell for sure what is in to the bundle. But following good practice this is intermediate certificate or root certificate (if particular CA do not use intermediate) of CA. The idea is server (application) need all the certificates in the chain (starting with root certificate) of particular CA. By all certificates in chain I mean

1. Root certificate of CA (usually selfsigned)
2. Intermediate certificate 1 (signed by root)
3. Intermediate certificate 2 (signed by Intermediate certificate 1)
4. ... and so on
5. Intermediate certificate n (signed by Intermediate certificate n-1)
6. Your certificate (signed by intermediate certificate n)

And to summarize: you should use entire file as `server.crt`

`server.key` is the private key you generate when create certificate request. Do you keep it?

`server.crt` and `server.key` can be literally arbitrary file names as far as they follow filesystem rules, exist, contain proper information and are described in the config file

`example.com.ca-bundle` should be used as `server.crt`

The private key you generate should be used as `server.key`

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to this. What is CA?

Comment: @ChrisRich CA=Certification Authority. In you case is Comodo

Comment: So on my localhost before purchasing the certificate, I generated a private key and a .csr file (Certificate Signing Request). So the files I have received from Comodo what are they used for?